# Outlook Web access, where do Mobile Devices come from?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

We have a corporate Exchange Server with Outlook Web Access. Under Options for some people (not for everyone) there's a Mobile Devices pane where their, well, mobile devices are enumerated. By circumstantial evidence, those are the devices that sync with Exchange Server via ActiveSync.

Question - where is this information stored? Exchange Server uses AD as the information storage - right? Does someone know if the devices are in the AD, too, and if so, what are the relevant schema objects?

Answer (score 1):

In the Exchange Manager, you can see the various categories in the Address book, and the properties of that object has an LDAP search filter that defines the objects that appear in that category.

So go look at the filter and answer your own question.  :)  (I do not have an Exchange system to go look the answer up on at the moment).